# Swift error: fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mapkit, mkpointannotation

I am new to Swift language. I've created a MapKit app that retrieves `MKPointAnnotation` data (lat, log and title) recursively from a Sqlite DB (latest FMDB stack).

The purpose is to put a bunch of interest points on a `MKMapViewDelegate`. I've tried w/out an array but the `mapView.addAnnotation` overwrites any point and shows only the last one on the map, so I'm trying with an array.

I've create a function, but I get the error "fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer" in runtime when wpoint array is called.

Here's the code:

```
func initializeRoute()
{

    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    var resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Route", withArgumentsInArray: nil)

    // DB Structure

    var DBorder:        String = "order"        // Int and Primary Index
    var DBlatitude:     String = "latitude"     // Float
    var DBlongitude:    String = "longitude"    // Float

    // Array declaration
    var wpoint: [MKPointAnnotation] = []

    // Loop counter init
    var counter: Int = 0

    if (resultSet != nil) {
        while resultSet.next() {
            counter = counter + 1

            wpoint[counter].coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                (resultSet.stringForColumn(String(DBlatitude)) as NSString).doubleValue,
                (resultSet.stringForColumn(String(DBlongitude)) as NSString).doubleValue
            )
            wpoint[counter].title = resultSet.stringForColumn(DBorder)
            mapView.addAnnotation(wpoint[counter])

        }
    }

    sharedInstance.database!.close()

}
```

`println ("Coordinate = \(wpoint.coordinate)")` show all data, I'm messing something within array declaration...

Answer (score 3):

The array declaration:

```
var wpoint: [MKPointAnnotation] = []
```

creates an *empty* array (zero elements).

Then, as the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW1) says:

> It is not possible to insert additional items into the array using subscripting:

which is why you get the "fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer" error later on this line:

```
wpoint[counter].coordinate = ...
```

Instead, as the documentation also says, use the `append` method or the `+=` operator.

Either way, you'll need to create an `MKPointAnnotation` object at each iteration, set its properties, add it to the array, and then pass it to `addAnnotation`.  For example:

```
var wpoint: [MKPointAnnotation] = []

if (resultSet != nil) {
    while resultSet.next() {

        let pa = MKPointAnnotation()

        pa.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
            (resultSet.stringForColumn(String(DBlatitude)) as NSString).doubleValue,
            (resultSet.stringForColumn(String(DBlongitude)) as NSString).doubleValue
        )

        pa.title = resultSet.stringForColumn(DBorder)

        wpoint.append(pa)
        //wpoint += [pa]  //alternative way to add object to array

        mapView.addAnnotation(pa)
    }
}
```

Please note a few additional things:

1. The `wpoint` array is not really necessary in the first place since you are adding annotations one at a time using `addAnnotation` (singular) and the code is not doing anything else with `wpoint`.
2. If you really want to use `wpoint` and add annotations to the map "all at once", then in the loop, you should add the annotations only to the array and then ***after*** the loop, call `addAnnotations` (plural) once and pass it the whole array.
3. The original code which used `counter` as the array index was assuming that the first index was `1` (`counter` was initialized to `0` but it is incremented at the top of the loop).  In Swift and many other languages, array indexes are zero-based.
4. A minor point but the code in the question is not "recursively" retrieving data.  It is retrieving the data iteratively.  Recursively would be if, for example, the `initializeRoute` method called itself.

Comment: Thanks Anna, I've solved redeclaring the Array:`var wpoint: Array<MKPointAnnotation> = Array()` and now it works! :)